# Set Sharepoint task due date based on workflow status

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I'm new to SharePoint but most of it seems pretty straight forward but I've hit a problem and haven't been able to find a way around it so far.

I'm trying to set/enforce Service Level Agreements (SLA's) for different departments based on the department the task is assigned to. I was going to do this based on the workflow status that generates the task but am open to any other suggestions.

My workflow for requesting funds for an approved project goes through several stages (Project management validation, Finance Admin validation; Finance manager validation, Fixed assets authorization) and each one has a slightly different SLA. For this reason, I cant just add an arbitrary value to the start date for the calculated column associated to the task.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The option I'd go with here is to use If/Then blocks in my workflow code based on the current stage. Something like this:

```
If Stage = Project Management Validation Then
  Set DueDate to Today+5
Else If Stage = Finance Admin Validation Then
  Set DueDate to Today+3
```

etc.

Hope this helps!